# Rails 3 - NoMethodError for method 'new' in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and am trying to do it without scaffolding so I'll REALLY learn it. I looked through railstutorial.org, but it diverged from what my project was doing so I generated scaffolding in another rails project and copy-edited code over.

Environment:
Ubuntu Lucid, 
ruby 1.9.3p125, 
rails 3.2.1

I am getting this error when going to the root of the application http://localhost:3000/

```
NoMethodError in DreamController#new

undefined method `new' for Dream:Module
Rails.root: /vagrant/dream

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/dream_controller.rb:5:in `new'
```

Here's my routes.rb

```
Dream::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :dreams do
    resources :interpretations
  end
  root :to => 'dream#new'
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
class DreamController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dream = Dream.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  def create
    @dream = Dream.new(params[:dream])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dream.save
        format.html { redirect_to @dream, notice: 'Dream was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/dream/new.html.erb is just:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

app/views/dream/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@dream) do |f| %>
  <% if @dream.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@dream.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this dream from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @dream.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :text %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my model (in 2 separate files):

```
class Dream < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :text, :presence => true
  has_many :interpretations
end

class Interpretation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :text, :presence => true
  belongs_to :dream
end
```

I've googled for a few hours now and can't figure this out. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I think it is related to my model. I get this error in rails console  



  
  
`1.9.3p125 :001 > @dream = Dream.new  
 NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for Dream:Module`

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem: I created my rails project with `rails new dream` and had a model 'Dream' as well. Rails was looking at the application class instead of the model class. I got an error about Dream already existing when I created the model and hand hacked my way around that (in retrospect, a horrible idea). This has been very frustrating but I have learned quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the controller name plural:

```
root :to => 'dreams#new'
```

and remember to restart the server when changing the routing configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for replying! This gives me the error: 

`uninitialized constant DreamsController`

I renamed my DreamController to DreamsController and am now getting the original error again...